# Django constraint between ManyToManyField and ForeignKey

Tags: django, database, django-models, orm

Consider I have following models:

```
class Cargo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Cargo, blank=True)
```

I want to avoid situation when I add some cargo object to box with different owner. For example:

```
cargo = Cargo(owner=1)
box = Box(owner=2)
box.add(cargo)
```

How to add such a constraint on a model level?

Comment: Hi, can a Box be a part of multiple Cargos? Or is each box part of a single cargo? I see you have it as a ManyToManyField, but I want to understand if conceptually this is the way it needs to be modeled

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that a great solution to this problem would be to define a custom RelatedManager that overrides the add() method and validates that the user is the same before you actually do the link. However, after searching through the internet for a while, I was unable to find a way to do a custom RelatedManager on the ManyToManyField (docs on [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager)).

As a workaround, I would recommend that you create a method on the Box model called `addCargo` which you use to add cargo. The method could then enforce the validation of the users before adding the cargo. It could look like:

```
class Box(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='')
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Cargo, blank=True)

    def addCargo(self, cargo):
        if self.owner.id != cargo.owner.id:
            raise ValueError("cargo and box must have same user")
        self.tags.add(cargo)
```

And your code to add the cargo would look like:

```
cargo = Cargo(owner=1)
box = Box(owner=2)
box.addCargo(cargo)
```

Hope this helps!